# Convert bitstring to byte in java

Tags: java, byte

I need to set each bit in 1 byte in Java.

```
bit7 -  1,
bit6 -  1,
bit5 - 1,
bit4 -  0,
bit3 – 0,
bit2 – 0,
bit1 – 0,
bit0 – 0
```

I've written:

```
byte extra_dop = 0b00000111;
```

but got the following error:

> binary literals are not supported in -source 1.5   (use -source 7 or
>   higher to enable binary literals)

Comment: have you tried `byte extra_dop = 0111b;` ?

Comment: Well what version of Java are you using, and is using Java 7 an option?

Answer (score 10):

Binary literal were introduced in Java7.

Use following for older version:

```
byte b = Byte.parseByte("00000111", 2);
```

Comment: since he wants primitive bytes, not Byte Objects, he should use `parseByte` instead of `valueOf`.

Comment: With autoboxing never noticed difference. Thanks for pointing, updated answer.

Comment: `Byte.parseByte("11111111", 2);` -> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range

Answer (score 4):

As the error message says, the `0b...` syntax did not exist yet in Java 5 (which is what you seem to be using); it was introduced with Java 7. If you are using Java 7, make sure your compiler settings (in your IDE or build file) are set so that it accepts Java 7 syntax.

Bits are normally counted from the right to the left, so if you say bit 7 is 1, bit 6 is 1, etc. then I would expect the binary number to be `11100000` instead of `00000111`.

To write this in source code in a Java version older than Java 7, you could simply write it as a hexadecimal or decimal number:

```
// Hexadecimal
byte extra_dop = (byte)0xE0; // or did you mean 0x07?

// Decimal
byte extra_dop = (byte)224; // or did you mean 7?
```

You could also use `Integer.parseInt()` with radix 2:

```
byte extra_dop = (byte)Integer.parseInt("11100000", 2);
```

(Note, you could also use `Byte.parseByte` but it will not accept `11100000` since it exceeds the range of the signed `byte` type).

Answer (score 0):

<s>That's not the way we do things in Java. Have a look at the [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) class, it's a much more convenient way of setting bit flags.</s>

Hmpfh. Let me rephrase that. Java is an Object Oriented language where there are efficient and Object Oriented ways of doing things in a more developer-friendly way than with bit operators. I'd suggest you use [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), as it makes your code much more readable, and it can support many more flags than a simple bit mask. Better?

Comment: "That's not the way we do things in Java." That's far too general a statement. While `BitSet` is an option, using a single `byte` value is a perfectly legitimate option too.

Comment: I agree that it's technically valid, but "Effective Java Item 47: Know and use the libraries" suggests that I should use existing solutions instead of reinventing them.

Comment: It depends on the context. Sometimes it's appropriate to use `BitSet`, other times it isn't. Knowing the libraries exist allows you to make that decision. Suppose we're storing a million entries like this - creating a million `BitSet` objects may be prohibitively expensive compared with just creating a million-byte array. The OP apparently only wants to store 8 flags, so the "it can support more flags" isn't a benefit in this case. I think it's reasonable to suggest looking into it - but I'd have done that as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to accomplish. If you just want to assign a value that won't be binary changed then what you are doing is just fine, but to use that functionallity you will have to compile specifying that javac will receive a source code that complies with java 7 (that is what the error messaging is saying). To do this depends on the way you are compiling, if you are using Netbeans or Eclipse then you will do this on the project properties configuration (just right click on the project and look for the properties, it will open a dialog, I don't remember right now where the source code compatibility is in each IDE, but I am almost sure it is right in the main screen of the dialog).

However if you want to edit the number later using bit operations then you will need to work like @Sean said using BitSet (actually you could also use bit operations directly on the numbers like we do in C/C++, it is just not confortable, but possible).